# Javascript : Delete [ ] in a table [ [ {} , {} ] ]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a table with a boucle FOR in javascript.

But I push tables, so my final table is:

```
[ [{},{}],[{},{}] ]
```

but I would like:

```
[{},{}]
```

How can I delete [ ] in a table.

My code :

```
this.table = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numberUnicorn; i++) {
  this.subMember = this.itemService.getUnicornMembership().subscribe((items) => {
    this.table.push(items);
  });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your code to get the results mentioned?

Comment: Do you mean table or array ? If array you can use `concat` to merge 2 arrays

Comment: Assuming your table is stored in the variable `t`: If what you want is just `[{}, {}]` and your table (`t`) is `[ [{},{}],[{},{}] ]`, you'd have to [*clone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) (not directly reference) one of the rows (`[{}, {}]`) and set `t` to that value. If you want to delete one of the rows, use the `delete` keyword with the appropriate index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concat to merge array

```
this.table = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberUnicorn; i++) {
        this.subMember = this.itemService.getUnicornMembership().subscribe(items => {
        this.table = this.table.concat(items);
    });
```

Or with ES6

```
this.table.push(...items)
```